# Как получить часовой пояс на Python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте. Нужно получить номер часового пояса на питоне time.timezone выдаёт стоил вроде.-14000 а мне нужно получить например для Москвы 3.
Кто нибудь подскажет как это сделать. Заранее спасибо

Comment: 14 400 секунд / 3600 = 4 часа (в Москве уже почти год как UTC+4)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Getting computer's UTC offset in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3168096/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168096/getting-computers-utc-offset-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для работы с временными зонами сами разработчики Python рекомендуют использовать модуль [pytz](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/2012d)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить верное значение для разных дат, необходимо использовать [базу временны́х зон (zoneinfo)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), которая хранит правила смены часовых поясов в мире. В Москве эти правила  менялись в последние годы.

В Питоне, [`tzlocal` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tzlocal) позволяет вернуть `pytz.timezone` объект, который содержит правила для локальной часовой зоны:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

tz = get_localzone() # local timezone 
d = datetime.now(tz) # or some other local date 
utc_offset = d.utcoffset().total_seconds()
```

Этот код возвращает текущий часовой пояс в переносимой манере с учётом правил, предоставляемых установленной версией [`pytz` модуля](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

В большинстве случаев можно ограничиться стандартной библиотекой:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

d = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()  # local time
utc_offset = d.utcoffset() // timedelta(seconds=1)
```

В редких случаях, на системе такой как Windows, которая не предоставляет доступ к zoneinfo, этот код [может вернуть ошибочное значение](http://bugs.python.org/issue1647654).

Дополнительные варианты, которые обходят эту проблему и/или варианты для старых версий Питона, [можно найти здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3168394/4279).