# Определение текущего часового пояса с помощью python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, timezone

Сейчас я озадачился одной проблемой, и мне необходимо суметь определить текущий часовой пояс и, соответственно, время в зависимости от пояса. Нужна функция типа:

```
tz = getCurTimeZone()
time = getCurTime(timeZone=tz)
```

Никак не могу найти подобное.
Также, не могу понять один термин - везде пишут, про локальное время(localtime). Это время с учётом часового пояса, или, то которое по умолчанию для всех (какой-то дефолтный часовой пояс)?

В общем нужен скрипт, при вызове которого из разных стран, показывалось бы свое время, в зависимости от часового пояса. Возможна ли реализация такого скрипта?

Comment: Локальное время — то, которое установлено на данном компьютере. Если пользователь корректно настроит его и часовой пояс, то соответственно это будет время в местном часовом поясе. `datetime.datetime.now()` или `time.localtime()` именно его и выводят — для чего вам знать именно часовой пояс?

Comment: Как получить часовой пояс на Python https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/135134/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python

Comment: Спасибо, @andreymal. Действительно, логично использовать время, установленное на пользовательском компьютере